# Replace all lines between two patterns (inclusive) with a file content

Tags: command-line, text-processing, sed, regex

All is said in the title , I want to replace all lines between two patterns with a a file content.

**file1**

```
line 1
line 2
foo
foobar
bar
line 6
line 7
```

**file2**

```
line 3
line 4
line 5
```

**desired file**

```
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4
line 5
line 6
line 7
```

Tried many sed commands nothing works for me , closest command below successfully matchs lines between foo and bar but replace them with "$(cat file2)" string and not file content.

```
sed '/foo/{:a;N;/bar/!ba;N;s/.*\n/$(cat file2)/};p' file1
```

Comment: Here is a ugly workaround: `printf '%s\n' "$(sed '/^foo$/,$d' file1 && cat file2 && sed -e '/^bar$/,$!d' -e '/^bar$/d' file1)" > desired-file` or `(sed '/^foo$/,$d' file1 && cat file2 && sed -e '/^bar$/,$!d' -e '/^bar$/d' file1) > desired-file`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are close, I think - your main issue is that `$(cat file2)` is going to be treated as literal within single quotes - you should be using the built-in `r` command:

> `r filename`
>
> Queue the contents of filename to be read and inserted into the output
>   stream at the end of the current cycle, or when the next input line is
>   read. Note that if filename cannot be read, it is treated as if it
>   were an empty file, without any error indication.

So:

```
sed '
  /foo/{
    :a
    N
    /\nbar$/!ba
    r file2
    d
  }
' file1
```

If you want to wrangle this into a one-liner there's a trick you'll need to prevent sed from treating everything after the `r` as part of the filename:

```
sed -e '/foo/{:a; N; /\nbar$/!ba; r file2' -e 'd;}' file1
```

Comment: +1 as it works for the generic example above .. God knows why it didn't work for my xml files.. managed to find another way to solve my problem though thanks for helping.